# What is the difference between remember, recall and mention?

Tags: meaning, difference

I know that "remember" means "not to forget"...but when I translate "recall" or "mention" it gives me the same answer(I use a google translate and the dictionary)

I'm confused and can't find the difference between them...Could somebody help me?

Comment: We need to understand what exactly is confusing so that we can give you a better answer. What definitions did you look at and why didn't they help? There is a post on [meta] that gives more information on the types of details that are helpful: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161

Comment: Also, if you are trying to learn a word equivalent to one in your language, you should add that word to your question. Possibly someone who is bilingual will have additional insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remember something you did (*remember doing sth*) or remember something you should do (*remember to do*).

You can only recall something you did (*recall doing sth*).

*Remembering* and *recalling* are about making sure that something is present in *your own memory*.

If you want to make sure that something is present in someone else's memory, then you remind them that they should do it (*remind sb to do sth*)

*Mentioning*… I don't really understand why you mention? It is bringing something to someone's *attention*, **not** to someone's *memory*.

Comment: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/stop-answering-close-worthy-questions?cb=1